# ruby bundle install fails with (Errno::EEXIST)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10. I installed rvm and ruby 1.9.3 on top of it and gem rails and bundle.
trying to run

```
bundle install
```

or better so

```
rvmsudo bundle install
```

both gives me the same error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/resque/resque.git
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/snir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': File exists - /home/snir/.rvm/bin/bundle (Errno::EEXIST)
    from /home/snir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /home/snir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/snir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/snir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
```

and so it goes..

I could not get around it. reinstalling bundle didn't help, so I reinstall the ruby and that didn't help as well so I completely remove RVM and reinstalled it and the problem remains.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BUNDLE_PATH was set to /home/snir/.rvm/bin/bundle which conflict with existing path.
To check what my BUNDLE_PATH was I used:

```
bundle config
```

and to change it:

```
bundle config path "/home/snir/.bundle"
```

(or whatever other path I wanted)

Answer (score 2):

error is that the '/home/snir/.rvm/bin/bundle' already exists.

I would check to see if this dir exists, and what the write permission on it is.

My guess is that you made this dir with sudo or something and it can't be written to.

Perhaps rm it, and try again?

Comment: but it's not a dir, it's the bundle binary. changing it would make bundle unavailable isn't it?

Comment: the error is that it is trying to make a dir with that name, which sounds like it is trying to use that as the dir to write bundled gems into.  Perhaps you have an odd BUNDLE_PATH set?